# Navigating within a navigation page not showing navbar

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, navigation, prism

I have a fairly linear Prism/Xamarin.Forms app that I am having trouble with the navigation. If the user opens the app and has already started some work, I need to skip ahead a couple pages like this:

```
navigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/pageA/pageB");
```

I have registered the NavigationPage type in the "RegisterTypes" method of my PrismApplication inherited class. Page B shows the nav/title bar just fine.

On "pageB" are some buttons to take the user to other pages. Based on the user's past usage, these buttons might take the user to pageC, with a parameter, like this:

```
navigationService.NavigateAsync("pageC?mode=x");
```

In this case, pageC correctly displays the navigation bar with the back arrow, page title, and toolbaritems.

or they might skip over pageC and go directly to pageD or pageE, like this:

```
navigationService.NavigateAsync("pageC/pageD");
```

This would leave the navigation stack like this:

```
/NavigationPage/pageA/pageB/pageC/pageD
```

In this case, pageD does not show any of the navigation bar, title, toolbar items, etc. Nothing I have tried will do it, other than using an absolute URI to rebuild the entire navigation stack.

I should mention that I have already tried explicitly setting the "useModalNavigation" parameter of the NavigateAsync method to false in the last call that doesn't work, and that doesn't do anything.

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

I am using Prism 6.3(Unity), Xamarin Forms 2.4, VS for Mac v7.2.2 with Xamarin.Android 8

Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: Are each of the pages ContentPage's or do you have some other type of page in the Stack? Can you try updating to the latest Prism 7 preview and see if that resolves the issue? There are a number of bug fixes with NavigationPage's in Prism 7. If that doesn't solve your issue please provide a link to a sample that duplicates the issue.

Comment: Yes, they are all "ContentPage"s. I have not tried the Prism 7 preview yet, but I will.

Comment: upgrading to prism 7 looks promising.